When forwarding a message can I rename its attachment?
In Gmail I want to forward a message containing an attachment but rename it.
Is there a way to do this in Gmail?

I use Linux Debian 12.6 with an email client called Betterbird (derived from Thunderbird) to access my gmail account.
When sending an email with an attachment, I am able to right click on the attachment notification which allows me to (amongst other options such as open and remove) rename the attachment..
Other email clients may work in a similar fashion.
